# Redirect from an HTML page with querystring?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to redirect from an HTML page with querystring  along with avoiding XSS on querystring ?

As currently we are redirecting with the following :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        window.location="https://ccc.com/aaa/?whr=urn:aaa:sss";
  </script>
```

But when the application tested with third party security, it reported vulnerability with  ?whr= . Like https://ccc.com/aaa/?whr=%22%3E%3Cqss%3E.

Please give us guidance to overcome this vulnerability.

Comment: Sanitize the query string once you land on the new page and do some js check(even if is not secure)

Answer (score 0):

You may get this message because of the appear of the `:` after the `?` on the url parameters.

On code behind, when you make the url string, encode the parameters with the

```
Server.UrlEncode(string s);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx